# Negate the null-coalescing operator

Tags: c#, null-coalescing-operator

I have a bunch of strings I need to use .Trim() on, but they can be null.  It would be much more concise if I could do something like:

```
string endString = startString !?? startString.Trim();
```

Basically return the part on the right if the part on the left is NOT null, otherwise just return the null value.  I just ended up using the ternary operator, but is there anyway to use the null-coalescing operator for this purpose?

Comment: I don't think so, tbh what is wrong with `!string.IsNullOrEmpty(startString) ? startString.Trim() : null;`

Comment: As I understand your question, you want to propagate null i.e. If the string is null, return null. Otherwise retun the trimmed string. Is that correct? If that is the case, there is no built in operator or method for doing so. You can use a ternary operator (as you done) or write a method.

Comment: I'm still waiting for this operator to be part of the language :(

Comment: I liked @sixlettervariables approach when we need `empty string` to be returned even if startString is null.

Comment: It sounds like what you're really after is a `?. :` ternary operator; if the left hand operand is non-null, access the appropriate member, but otherwise evaluate the right-hand side.  Sample usage: `theValue = someThing?.SomeProperty : defaultValue;`  That would be a useful operator, but its syntax and binding would be totally unlike anything else in the language.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could create an extension method which returns `null` when it tries to trim the value.

```
public String TrimIfNotNull(this string item)
{
   if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(item))
     return item;
   else
    return item.Trim();
}
```

Note you can't name it Trim because extension methods can't override instance methods.

Comment: It feels so wrong that this works when `item` is null... But, I did confirm it works. `string s = null; s.TrimIfNotNull();` No `NullReferenceException` like you'd get with a regular instance method (even one that doesn't reference to any members).

Comment: It makes perfect sense why it works.  Extension methods are nothing more than static methods which are appended to an object.  Really there is no reason why they shouldn't work.  The class can't depend on anything they do since they weren't created when the original class was, and they can't access any of the private methods or object. It would be hindering to not allow the to be used on a null object (although I do admit it is a little odd at first).

Comment: Yes, the climax of that feature is the IfNotNull extension method : `public V IfNotNull<T, V>(this T @in, Func<T,V> access)`

Answer (score 12):

**Not to spec:** Not that I like it, but you could use:

```
string endString = (startString ?? String.Empty).Trim();
```

**To spec, better as an Extension method like @Kevin's:**

```
string endString = (startString == null ? null : startString.Trim());
```

Comment: Does not propagate null as he asked for

Comment: this doesn't return null if startString is null.

Comment: Took me a second read to realize he actually wanted the null... @Kevin has the right idea in that case.

Comment: Why not use `string.IsNullOrEmpty()`?

Comment: He wants null's to stay null's and empty to stay empty, I gathered.

Comment: I liked your first approach. Return `empty string` even if the startString is `null`. This is helpful when assigning value to a textbox control.  It would be helpful if you can add this explanation in the answer itself.

Answer (score 4):

```
string endString = string.IsNullOrEmpty(startString) ? startString : startString.Trim();
```

Though I've also gone the route of writing a string extension method called "safeTrim" which does what you're describing in one method instead of having to use this recipe every time.  Check out [Kevin's respone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2852875/negate-the-null-coalescing-operator/2852897#2852897) for the code.

**EDIT**: wow I had it all kinds of backwards, wrongly named variables and reversed ternary operators, all the more reason to write one extension method and code check it better than I did!

Comment: Ninja-edited thanks to Frank's comment reminding me that it's `string.IsNullOrEmpty(foo)` and not `foo.IsNullOrEmpty()`

Comment: Checks for empty. Not what he is asking for

Comment: Ah, yes.  At first I thought "the empty check is an effective no-op" because the normal use case is to just return `endString` at the end instead of `null`, but I had explicitly put `null` at the end.  Changed to the normal use case and it makes the null check effectively a no-op.

Comment: Also, this will throw a `NullReferenceException` if `startString == null`. You might want to switch the ordering of the expressions ;)

Comment: Excellent, didn't even think of an extension method.  Thanks.

Comment: And how can `endString` be in scope already when it is defined within this particular statement? I think you need to do some more ninja editing...

Comment: I think you mean `string endString = string.IsNullOrEmpty(startString) ? startString : startString.Trim();`.  He wants the null string if it is null/empty, and he wants to trim it if it is _not_ null/empty.

Comment: I don't think he mentioned Null **or Empty**, just null.

Comment: @Sarah indeed I did, I had it very much backwards and even chose the wrong variable name for one branch anyway, wow  *headdesk*

Answer (score 4):

Starting with C# 6.0 (.NET Framework 4.6 / Visual Studio 2015) you can use [null-conditional member access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators):

```
 string? endString = startString?.Trim();
```

Comment: should be ?. instead of .?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the necromancy, but I was having this same problem and I solved this using a lambda operation. It isn't the prettiest, but it keeps my code succinct.

It's a shame C# doesn't support static imports or individual function imports, but anyway:

Define this function somewhere:

```
private static TResult N<TParent,TResult>(TParent parent, Func<TParent,TResult> operation) {
    if( parent == null ) return default(TResult);
    return operation( parent );
}
```

Then to use it in your example:

```
String endString = N(startString, s => s.Trim());
```

The `N` function returns `null` if the first argument is null, otherwise it will evaluate the specified lambda function with the value as the argument.

You can nest it, of course, like so. For example, to safely dereference a long chain, e.g.

```
String someValue = someObject.SomeProperty.SomeOtherProperty.SomeMethod().SomeFinalProperty;
```

if any of those properties or methods returns null then you have to insert null checks everywhere, or you could do this:

```
String someValue = N(N(N(N(someObject, o => o.SomeProperty), o => o.SomeOtherProperty), o => o.SomeMethod()), o => o.SomeFinalProperty);
```

As I said, it isn't the prettiest :)

You could simplify this by making `N` an extension method of `System.Object`, like so:

```
String someValue = someObject.N( o => o.SomeProperty ).N( o => o.SomeOtherProperty ).N( o => o.SomeMethod() ).N( o => o.SomeFinalProperty );
```

...which I think is a lot tidier.

Comment: A class-constrained generic would seem better than `System.Object`, and I think it would be good to have some variations that accept various numbers of "extra" parameters.  There can be a huge difference in performance between a lambda that has to capture anything (including `this`) and one that doesn't, so allowing parameters to be passed explicitly rather than captured can be a big win.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
string endString = (startString ?? "").Trim();
```

This uses an empy string if startString is null. This, however, **does not** return null when `endString` is null.

Fast-forward to 2021:
10 years later `startString?.Trim()` is definitely the better option. And this **does** return `null`.

Comment: If startString is null he want endString to be null. Your sample will return string.Empty

Answer (score -1):

The following doesn't propagate null but it accepts null as a parameter and returns an empty string in that case.

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;  // you need to add a reference to Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll

    ...
    string endString = Strings.Trim(startString);
    ...
```

<sub>duck&run...</sub>

Answer (score -1):

As as side note, if you're using .NET 4, there's a new convenient method [`String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace.aspx) which you can use.

Comment: Interesting method, but seems orthogonal to the problem the OP has.