# Trim Textbox value by considering NULL

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio

Can you tell me if TrimNull() is redundant and if I should be using an alternative?

For example:

```
string username = UsernameTextBox.Text.TrimNull();
```

I am told there is no definition or extension method. Perhaps there is a reference I am missing?

**UPDATE**:

What is the most `readable` way to return `empty string` if the value is NULL?

Comment: What is this function? There is no such function defined for string.

Comment: What is TrimNull() .. it isnt C#

Comment: What should that strange method do? There's no `TrimNull` in the framework. Maybe somebody has added an extension and you're missing a reference to that dll. But how shall we know?

Comment: Assuming you're referring to [this `TrimNull()` method](http://vbnet.mvps.org/index.html?code/core/trimnull.htm), it is not very useful here. `UsernameTextBox` is a text box, and it's pretty hard for an end user to embed null characters in a text box.

Comment: This code was inherited from a previous developer. The funny thing is this code is live, and it works!

Comment: @Jono If you've got the project open in visual studio, you can right click on `TrimNull()` and click "Go to definition" to find out exactly how the original developer defined that extension method. You can then paste that code into your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create your own extension-method for that, if you like:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string TrimNull(this string value)
    {
        return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value) ? value : value.Trim();
    }
}
```

Add this to your project and your code will work.

This is just an alternative.

Comment: @Lijo Sure, that would work =) Except it will never return `null` if that's what the OP wanted, but who knows =) Your answer is valid if you always want a string that is not null.

Answer (score 5):

There's no such function as `TrimNull(String)` - it wouldn't do anything. A string is either a null or not null, it can't contain a mixture of both. If the string were null, a static function `TrimNull(myString)` would not be able to 'remove' anything from the string. If it weren't null, there would be no `NULL` to remove. Even worse, if TrimNull were an instance method `myString.TrimNull()` would simply cause an exception if myString were `NULL` - because you cannot invoke any method on a null reference.

- If your goal is to trim whitespace characters surrounding the string, just use `myString.Trim()`.
- If your goal is to detect whether the string is null, use `myString == NULL`
- If your goal is to detect whether the string is empty or null use `String.IsNullOrEmpty(myString)`
- If your goal is to trim trailing null characters (`\0`) from data stream, try the following:

  `myString.TrimEnd(new char[] { '\0' } )`

But as Frédéric Hamidi said, if you're referring to the latter, the user will have a hard time getting null characters into a TextBox, so you shouldn't worry about that scenario in your processing of their input.

Comment: It's worse than that. If the string were null, an exception would happen, because there would be no String object to invoke the TrimNull() method with.

Comment: @CharlieKilian precisely. I'll modify my answer to reflect that.

Comment: It could be an extension of string.

Comment: That is something that has always bugged me about the string functions in the .NET framework. I wish they were implemented as static methods on the String object. You can't even write them yourself as extension methods, because you can't write extension methods for static objects. Alas.

Comment: @TimSchmelter It could be, but as I said, if such an extension method existed and did what the name suggests, it would be obsolete.

Comment: @Alain: As someone has posted, there's a VB6 function `TrimNull` http://vbnet.mvps.org/index.html?code/core/trimnull.htm Note: not every _null_ is an undefined value: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_set

Comment: @TimSchmelter This seems to be calling the null character (`\0`) '`NULL`' - which while two different things, I can see why such a function would be called "TrimNull". I'll edit my answer to take this scenario into account.

Answer (score 2):

I usually use String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(), like this:

```
string username = (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(UsernameTextBox.Text) ? 
    null : UsernameTextBox.Text.Trim());
```

That way, if the `.Text` property is null, it doesn't cause an exception.

Answer (score 1):

Use [null-coalescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) as mentioned in @sixlettervariables answer in [Negate the null-coalescing operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2852875/negate-the-null-coalescing-operator)

```
string username = (UsernameTextBox.Text ?? String.Empty).Trim();
```

Answer (score 0):

A string being NULL is not its value. its a state. It means it has not been assigned a memory (coz its a reference type). Had it been a value type datatype it woudld be assigned a default value automatically like for int its 0 and so on

u should use

```
if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(UsernameTextBox.Text))
    string username = UsernameTextBox.Text.Trim();
```